# Assignment methods are not aliased properly

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, alias, attr-accessor

Consider the following code:

```
class Cattr
  attr_accessor :attr
  alias_method :a_attr, :attr
  alias_method :a_attr=, :attr=
  def attr ; a_attr ; end
  def attr= value ; a_attr= value ; end
end
ca = Cattr.new
#⇒ #<Cattr:0x000000018974b0>
ca.attr
#⇒ nil
ca.attr = 42
#⇒ 42
ca.attr
#⇒ nil
```

What? The problem is not with aliasing method, defined by `attr_accessor`, aliasing *getter* works pretty fine:

```
class Cattr
  attr_accessor :attr
  # alias_method :a_attr=, :attr=
  alias_method :a_attr, :attr # still aliased
  # def attr= value ; a_attr= value ; end
  def attr ; a_attr ; end     # still aliased
end

ca = Cattr.new
#⇒ #<Cattr:0x000000018974b0>
ca.attr
#⇒ nil
ca.attr = 42
#⇒ 42
ca.attr
#⇒ 42   # sic!
```

*Sidenote*: aliasing `attr?` method works pretty fine too.

My question would be: is it a known ruby behaviour (aliasing setters is prohibited,) or I am missing something obvious?

Comment: @jörg-w-mittag Well, great now. How this question is a dup of the linked one? Please point to the answer there, that is applicable as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setter methods need explicit receivers. Your code:

```
def attr= value ; a_attr= value ; end
```

is not calling the setter `a_attr=`; it is assigning a value to a local variable `a_attr`.

To do what you want, you need to do:

```
def attr= value; self.a_attr= value; end
```

Comment: Thanks. Another thing I just discovered is that setter expects the only parameter. Being wrapped as “generic” `*args`, it results in `[val]` passed to setter instead of `val`.